# Android : How to save profile pictures for accounts as like google android contacts

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I have an android application where user can create categories and accounts under each category.Now what i wanted is i need to set a profile picture for each of these categories and accounts under it so that it should not take more memory by the application.Actually i need the same mechanism like in contacts application in our android mobiles where we can pick an image in any size as the profile picture and store it into the memory but it will not take more system memory.I don't know how Google is managing that and saving it into the application's internal memory or database.If anyone know about that please help me so that i can use the same mechanism in my application by consuming a small amount of memory for setting images for the thousands of accounts in my application.